# /include vs /include/linux in kernel source tree

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

In [linux kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/), some header files and directories are located directly at [/include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnuWA.png), but some others are located at [/include/linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LVg5.png). Why they just don't put everything into /include? What is the difference between /include and /include/linux?

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Comment: D, they're different headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But not only `linux/`, also `uapi/` and `asm-generic/` are special dirs inside of `include`. This generic "include" dir is heterogenous -- `include/linux` is the kernel itself: half of the 40MB of `include/`.

---

K&R "C" notes at the end of the chapter: "...for a much larger program more organization and more headers would be needed".

So from the beginning, also with medium size projects, it is all about organization. This is also reflected by the `<.h>` and `".h"`syntax, and the compiler rules for including. Also by the `#ifndef`... `#define` "protection", which is applied systematically. Linux kernel has *much* more organization.

I think I finally found a working example:

`kernel/sched/` by itself has small to medium dimensions. It has 8 header files, one of them `sched.h` which begins:

```
/*
 * Scheduler internal types and methods:
 */
#include <linux/sched.h>

...
```

This "local" sched.h only contains low level stuff.

---

This included `include/linux/sched.h` begins:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_SCHED_H
#define _LINUX_SCHED_H

/*
 * Define 'struct task_struct' and provide the main scheduler
 * APIs (schedule(), wakeup variants, etc.)
 */

#include <uapi/linux/sched.h>

#include <asm/current.h>

#include <linux/pid.h>
...
```

All this is actually very well documented and laid out.

The "uapi" include defines CLONE_ flags and SCHED_ policies (e.g. RR=2): for "export"/use by programs.

`asm/current.h` is low level to access the current task.

`linux/pid.h` as sibling is just as elementary as linux/sched.h.

--> `include/linux/` is the main central container for global "kernel" header files.

---

The other dirs -- the big rest -- in `include/` are partly for "importing" definitions i.e. integrating hardware. They belong more to drivers/  than to kernel/ or mm/ or fs/.

---

`include/sound/` is also interesting. `sound/sound_core.c` has:

```
/*
 * First, the common part.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/major.h>
#include <sound/core.h>
```

So it needs (linux-, kernel-) modules, errors and devices, plus it's own "Main header file for the ALSA driver devices...(1994-2001)" `sound/core.h`.